# Why the CLASSIFY action isn't applied by the iptables?

Tags: iptables, tc

Why might the following simple iptables rule not work:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 1194 -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:10
```

?

I'm trying to prioritize outgoing traffic to VPN. I am connected to the internet via a router with the OpenWrt. And I tried to add this rule to the iptables and corresponding qdisces and classes to the tc. There is no more rules in the POSTROUTING chain, so, as far as I understand, packets could not be "eaten" by some other rule. But `iptables -v -t mangle -L POSTROUTING` shows that there are few packets caught on connecting to the VPN and on disconnecting from it only. But when I'm working with it, the packets counter remain unchanged.

Comment: Probably, I found a cause of this behaviour. The thing is that, I am using the GL.iNet router and it has a so called "Routing/NAT Offloading" option which is on by default. I am currently not 100% sure, but it looks like it is some kind of optimization of traffic processing which, among of other, may exclude some packets from processing by the Linux kernel (i.e., in the `iptables`). If I ensure that it's right, I'll update this ticket.